# RegEx Convert XML to JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, json, parse-platform

This is a continuation of a previous question:
[I need to convert XML to Json in JavaScript on Parse.com's Cloud Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653460/i-need-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-javascript-on-parse-coms-cloud-code)

**Please don't down vote this because you don't believe RegEx is the right choice for this.  It's what I have to work with.**  If you have another idea of a way to do this, please let me know.  But it must run on Parse.com's Cloud Code.

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><api><products total-matched="1618" records-returned="1" page-number="1"><product><ad-id>1234</ad-id><supplier-name>Window World</supplier-name><supplier-category>3703703</supplier-category><buy-url>http://website.com</buy-url><currency>USD</currency><description>Window</description><image-url>http://website.com/windowa/80x80.jpg</image-url><in-stock>yes</in-stock><manufacturer-name>Window World</manufacturer-name><name>Half Pain Glass</name><price>31.95</price><retail-price>87.60</retail-price><sale-price>29.95</sale-price><sku>5938</sku><upc></upc></product><product><ad-id>1234</ad-id><supplier-name>Window World</supplier-name><supplier-category>3703703</supplier-category><buy-url>http://website.com</buy-url><currency>USD</currency><description>Window</description><image-url>http://website.com/windowa/80x80.jpg</image-url><in-stock>yes</in-stock><manufacturer-name>Window World</manufacturer-name><name>Half Pain Glass</name><price>31.95</price><retail-price>87.60</retail-price><sale-price>29.95</sale-price><sku>5938</sku><upc></upc></product><product><ad-id>1234</ad-id><supplier-name>Window World</supplier-name><supplier-category>3703703</supplier-category><buy-url>http://website.com</buy-url><currency>USD</currency><description>Window</description><image-url>http://website.com/windowa/80x80.jpg</image-url><in-stock>yes</in-stock><manufacturer-name>Window World</manufacturer-name><name>Half Pain Glass</name><price>31.95</price><retail-price>87.60</retail-price><sale-price>29.95</sale-price><sku>5938</sku><upc></upc></product><product><ad-id>1234</ad-id><supplier-name>Window World</supplier-name><supplier-category>3703703</supplier-category><buy-url>http://website.com</buy-url><currency>USD</currency><description>Window</description><image-url>http://website.com/windowa/80x80.jpg</image-url><in-stock>yes</in-stock><manufacturer-name>Window World</manufacturer-name><name>Half Pain Glass</name><price>31.95</price><retail-price>87.60</retail-price><sale-price>29.95</sale-price><sku>5938</sku><upc></upc></product></products></api>
```

RegEx Code:

```
var regex = /(<\w+[^<]*?)\s+([\w-]+)="([^"]+)">/;
            while(xml.match(regex)) xml = xml.replace(regex, '<$2>$3</$2>$1>'); // For attributes

            xml = xml.replace(/\s/g, ' ').  // Finds all the white space converts to single space
                    replace(/< *\?[^>]*?\? *>/g, ''). //Finds the XML header and removes it
                    replace(/< *!--[^>]*?-- *>/g, ''). //Finds and removes all comments
                    replace(/< *(\/?) *(\w[\w-]+\b):(\w[\w-]+\b)/g, '<$1$2_$3').
                    replace(/< *(\w[\w-]+\b)([^>]*?)\/ *>/g, '< $1$2>').
                    replace(/(\w[\w-]+\b):(\w[\w-]+\b) *= *"([^>]*?)"/g, '$1_$2="$3"').
                    replace(/< *(\w[\w-]+\b)((?: *\w[\w-]+ *= *" *[^"]*?")+ *)>( *[^< ]*?\b.*?)< *\/ *\1 *>/g, '< $1$2 value="$3">').
                    //replace(/ *(\w[\w-]+\b) *= *"([^>]*?)" */g, '< $1>$2').
                    replace(/< *(\w[\w-]+\b) *</g, '<$1>< ').
                    replace(/> *>/g, '>').
                    //replace(/< *\/ *(\w[\w-]+\b) *> *< *\1 *>/g, '').  // breaks the output?
                    replace(/"/g, '\\"').
                    replace(/< *(\w[\w-]+\b) *>([^<>]*?)< *\/ *\1 *>/g, '"$1":"$2",').
                    replace(/< *(\w[\w-]+\b) *>([^<>]*?)< *\/ *\1 *>/g, '"$1":{$2},').
                    replace(/< *(\w[\w-]+\b) *>(?=.*?< \/\1\},\{)/g, '"$1":[{').
                    split(/\},\{/).
                    reverse().
                    join('},{').
                    replace(/< *\/ *(\w[\w-]+\b) *>(?=.*?"\1":\[\{)/g, '}],').
                    split(/\},\{/).
                    reverse().
                    join('},{').
                    replace(/< \/(\w[\w-]+\b)\},\{\1>/g, '},{').
                    replace(/< *(\w[\w-]+\b)[^>]*?>/g, '"$1":{').
                    replace(/< *\/ *\w[\w-]+ *>/g,'},').
                    replace(/\} *,(?= *(\}|\]))/g, '}').
                    replace(/] *,(?= *(\}|\]))/g, ']').
                    replace(/" *,(?= *(\}|\]))/g, '"').
                    replace(/ *, *$/g, '');
```

Output:

```
"api": {
    "page-number": "1",
    "records-returned": "1",
    "total-matched": "1618",
    "products": {
        "product": {
            "ad-id": "1234",
            "supplier-name": "Window World",
            "supplier-category": "3703703",
            "buy-url": "http://website.com",
            "currency": "USD",
            "description": "Window",
            "image-url": "http://website.com/windowa/80x80.jpg",
            "in-stock": "yes",
            "manufacturer-name": "Window World",
            "name": "Half Pain Glass",
            "price": "31.95",
            "retail-price": "87.60",
            "sale-price": "29.95",
            "sku": "5938",
            "upc": ""
        },
        "product": {
            "ad-id": "1234",
            "supplier-name": "Window World",
            "supplier-category": "3703703",
            "buy-url": "http://website.com",
            "currency": "USD",
            "description": "Window",
            "image-url": "http://website.com/windowa/80x80.jpg",
            "in-stock": "yes",
            "manufacturer-name": "Window World",
            "name": "Half Pain Glass",
            "price": "31.95",
            "retail-price": "87.60",
            "sale-price": "29.95",
            "sku": "5938",
            "upc": ""
        },
        "product": {
            "ad-id": "1234",
            "supplier-name": "Window World",
            "supplier-category": "3703703",
            "buy-url": "http://website.com",
            "currency": "USD",
            "description": "Window",
            "image-url": "http://website.com/windowa/80x80.jpg",
            "in-stock": "yes",
            "manufacturer-name": "Window World",
            "name": "Half Pain Glass",
            "price": "31.95",
            "retail-price": "87.60",
            "sale-price": "29.95",
            "sku": "5938",
            "upc": ""
        },
        "product": {
            "ad-id": "1234",
            "supplier-name": "Window World",
            "supplier-category": "3703703",
            "buy-url": "http://website.com",
            "currency": "USD",
            "description": "Window",
            "image-url": "http://website.com/windowa/80x80.jpg",
            "in-stock": "yes",
            "manufacturer-name": "Window World",
            "name": "Half Pain Glass",
            "price": "31.95",
            "retail-price": "87.60",
            "sale-price": "29.95",
            "sku": "5938",
            "upc": ""
        }
    }
}
```

The last issue I'm having with this (that I know of) is this doesn't make repeating items a JSON array.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: If you can shift from RegEx approach to Javascript, then Have a look at http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json.

Comment: I tried that in the beginning, it doesn't work on Parse.com's Cloud  I got further with this RegEx.  Thanks

Comment: Try this [xml2json](http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html)

Comment: I tried that also, didn't work..  :(

Comment: There is no way that you would have the strength to touch this code on the event of the Parse.com's API changing. Also there is no way that anybody will ever want to debug this. You would be much better off converting your xml to a javascript object and then the object to JSON. At least there would be debuggable steps.

Comment: It's not Parse's api that makes the XML, so it doesn't mater if they change there API.  Parse doesn't have a built in xml to json conversion.  The data I'm able to get it only available via xml.

Comment: Have you investigated why the other solutions for converting xml to json have not worked with Parse.com's Cloud?

Comment: Yes, there is no dom support on Parse, and a few other issues.

Comment: Would you happen to have some comments about the algorithm used ? It'd be a pain in the ass to understand it through all those replaces ;)

Comment: Not really other than what I figured out...  It wasn't my original code.

Comment: Ok so we'll have to figure that out I'm afraid. Might take some time I guess.

Comment: I built an ugly demo to try to figure out what everything did. http://jsbin.com/iwisey/1/

Comment: I'm almost done figuring it out. I have to say, there are many flaws // strange things in his algorithm. Had I have time I'd try to correct it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27083/discussion-between-brad-and-loamhoof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so, note that it's a quick fix but nevertheless it seems to work. This will just ADD an array structure so your won't have several times the same key (but it won't destroy that key).
Change:

```
replace(/< *(\w[\w-]+\b) *>(?=.*?< \/\1\},\{)/g, '"$1":[{').
split(/\},\{/).
reverse().
join('},{').
replace(/< *\/ *(\w[\w-]+\b) *>(?=.*?"\1":\[\{)/g, '}],').
split(/\},\{/).
reverse().
join('},{').
```

which is an attempt to implement arrays.
And put :

```
replace(/< *(\w[\w-]+\b) *>(?=("\w[\w-]+\b)":\{.*?\},\2)(.*?)< *\/ *\1 *>/, '"$1":[$3],')
```

Note that I used pretty much his way of matching things. That seemed to work for you example at least.

Comment: I had to add .replace(/],\s*?".*?": *\[/g,',') to what you did to make it pass the JSON formatter jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com and then enclose the entire thing in {} braces. but it all seems to work now. Thanks again for the help! (product was coming up multiple times)

Comment: Still, the whole thing is pretty buggy, if I come up with something better I'll tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex is an interesting approach and it does seem a bit faster than working with node lists.  However, when speed is not the determining factor (as in OP's application) then this is not the best way to convert xml to js.  The regex code is around 1kb compressed.  For the same number of bytes you can build a fairly robust and reusable converter ... one that even copes with xml names space in different browsers.

I wrote the following code (compressed) and it processed OP's XML data fine.

```
    var xml2js=function(m,p){var f=1,o=2,d=3,n=4,j=7,c=8,h=9,l,b,a,k={},g=[];if(!p){p={}}if(typeof p=="string"){p={find:p}}p.xmlns=p.xmlns||"*";if(p.parse!="function"){p.parse=e}function e(i){return i.split(":").pop().replace(/^ows_/,"").replace(/[^a-z,A-Z,0-9]/g,"")}switch(m.nodeType){case h:a=(!p.find)?m.childNodes:(m.getElementsByTagNameNS)?m.getElementsByTagNameNS(p.xmlns,p.find.split(":").pop()):m.getElementsByTagName(p.find);for(l=0;l<a.length;l++){k=xml2js(a[l]);if(k){g.push(k)}}k=(g.length&&g.length==1)?g[0]:g;break;case f:if(m.attributes.length==0&&m.childNodes.length==1&&m.childNodes.item(0).nodeValue){k=m.childNodes.item(0).nodeValue}for(l=0;l<m.attributes.length;l++){b=p.parse(m.attributes.item(l).nodeName);k[b]=m.attributes.item(l).nodeValue}for(l=0;l<m.childNodes.length;l++){if(m.childNodes.item(l).nodeType!=d){b=p.parse(m.childNodes.item(l).nodeName);if(typeof k[b]=="undefined"){k[b]=xml2js(m.childNodes.item(l))}else{if(typeof k[b].push=="undefined"){k[b]=[k[b]]}k[b].push(xml2js(m.childNodes.item(l)))}}}break;case n:k="<![CDATA["+m.nodeValue+"]]>";break;case d:k=m.nodeValue;break;case c:k="";break;default:k=null}return k};
```

And then load and convert the xml:

```
    function test( ) {
        var nodeName = 'products'; // optional - any node name
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'CloudCode.xml', false);
        xhr.send();
        var js = xml2js( xhr.responseXML, nodeName );
        console.log(JSON.stringify( js, null, '\t'));
    }
```

Output:

```
    {
    "pagenumber": "1",
    "recordsreturned": "1",
    "totalmatched": "1618",
     "product": [
      {
        "adid": "1234",
        "suppliername": "Window World",
        "suppliercategory": "3703703",
         "buyurl": "http://website.com",


         etc...
```